# Program to find the adjacent cells in 2 dimension array

Tags: c, logic

Please share some logic to find all the adjacent cells of two dimension array. I have two logic but still I am hunting for the third best.

1). traverses all the cells and check if it is adjacent to the selected one.

2). directly jumps to the adjacent cells by calculating the index. I find this approach better to first one but one thing I don't like about it lots and lots of if conditions?

-Bhupesh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop from max(0, x-1) and max(0, y-1) to min(x+1, MAX_X) and min(y+1, MAX_Y) and skip (x,y).

For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int max(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) {
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return b;
    }
}

int min(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) {
        return a;
    }
    else {
        return b;
    }
}

void print_adjacent(int x, int y, int cols, int rows) {
    int lowest_x = max(x-1, 0);
    int highest_x = min(x+1, cols-1);
    int lowest_y = max(y-1, 0);
    int highest_y = min(y+1, rows-1);
    int i, j;

    for ( i = lowest_x; i <= highest_x; i++ ) {
        for ( j = lowest_y; j <= highest_y; j++ ) {
            if ( !(i == x && j == y) ) {
                printf("(%d, %d) is adjacent to (%d, %d)\n", i, j, x, y);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int num_cols = 10;
    int num_rows = 10;

    print_adjacent(0, 0, num_cols, num_rows);
    print_adjacent(0, 3, num_cols, num_rows);
    print_adjacent(4, 5, num_cols, num_rows);
    print_adjacent(9, 5, num_cols, num_rows);
    print_adjacent(9, 9, num_cols, num_rows);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: Not sure how much I can elaborate. The cells adjacent to (x, y) are those which satisfy the criteria (x-1 <= adj_x <= x+1, y-1 <= adj_y <= y+1), except (x, y) itself must be excluded, as well as any cells outside of the boundaries of the array. See the sample code I added.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the 'coded' reply.
 Somehow my net connection is not working at my home so I am not able to post my code. I will post it as soon as my connection is up.

Comment: Hi here is my code for finding the adjacent cells. The logic is written wrt my program..

Answer (score 0):

```
int SnakyArray::GetAliveNeighbourCount(int p_pRowIndex, int p_pColumnIndex)
{
    auto l_bRowDecrement    = false;
    auto l_bRowIncrement    = false;
    auto l_bCoulmnDecrement = false;
    auto l_bColumnIncrement = false;
    auto l_iAliveNeighbourCount = 0;

    if(p_pRowIndex - 1 > -1) l_bRowDecrement = true;
    if(p_pRowIndex + 1 < m_ROW_SIZE) l_bRowIncrement = true;

    if(p_pColumnIndex - 1 > -1) l_bCoulmnDecrement = true;
    if(p_pColumnIndex + 1 < m_COLUMN_SIZE) l_bColumnIncrement = true;

    if(l_bRowDecrement)
        //This is the adjacent cell.
        //l_iAliveNeighbourCount += m_PatternArray[p_pRowIndex - 1][p_pColumnIndex];

    if(l_bRowIncrement)
        //This is the adjacent cell
        //l_iAliveNeighbourCount += m_PatternArray[p_pRowIndex + 1][p_pColumnIndex];

    //Checking previous row
    if(l_bCoulmnDecrement)
    {
        //This is the adjacent cell
        //l_iAliveNeighbourCount +=  m_PatternArray[p_pRowIndex][p_pColumnIndex - 1];

        if(l_bRowDecrement)
            //This is the adjacent cell
            //l_iAliveNeighbourCount +=  m_PatternArray[p_pRowIndex - 1][p_pColumnIndex - 1];

        if(l_bRowIncrement)
            ////This is the adjacent cell
            //l_iAliveNeighbourCount +=  m_PatternArray[p_pRowIndex + 1][p_pColumnIndex - 1];
    }

    //Checking next row
    if(l_bColumnIncrement)
    {
        //This is the adjacent cell
        //l_iAliveNeighbourCount +=  m_PatternArray[p_pRowIndex][p_pColumnIndex + 1];

        if(l_bRowDecrement)
            //This is the adjacent cell
            //l_iAliveNeighbourCount +=  m_PatternArray[p_pRowIndex - 1][p_pColumnIndex + 1];

        if(l_bRowIncrement)
            //This is the adjacent cell
            //l_iAliveNeighbourCount +=  m_PatternArray[p_pRowIndex + 1][p_pColumnIndex + 1];
    }
    return l_iAliveNeighbourCount;
}
```

Comment: Hey!
Any comments on this Paul?